# WebResourceResponse doesn't show videos

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, instagram

To solve the current problem of displaying resources with Instagram I do the following:

1. Intercept the urls with ShouldInterceptRequest.
2. Load them with WebResourceResponse.

```
public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest (Android.Webkit.WebView sender, IWebResourceRequest request) {

string url = request.Url.ToString();

WebClient wc = new WebClient();

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url));

return new WebResourceResponse("", "", stream);

}
```

**This loads the images perfectly but the videos don't. Any ideas?**

I am not specifying the mimetype because when applying it manually I saw that the result is the same, it does not affect.

Comment: According to your description, where you want to play video? Webview? Can you use media control to play video?